# PHP5 PDO::lastInsertId

Tags: php, pdo

I am hoping to **not** have to write another request to mysqli to get the id of an inserted row.

I need to know if [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) is an asynchronous thread safe method.

Since this is a functionality question, i will provide a schematic instead of a library i wrote that handles PDO; However, I will provide if necessary.

---

### SCHEMATIC

```
$connect = mysqli->connect
$is_inserted = $connect->insert(...)
if($is_inserted){
     $last_insert_id = $connect->lastInsertId();
}
```

I need to make sure that a another user will not get someone elses insert_id if they are running the script simultaneously.

Comment: `lastInsertId` will get you the correct value, you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) say:

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client.

So, you should have no issues using `$connect->lastInsertId()`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I didn't think to check the mysql docs.